# How to JOIN a COUNT from a table, and then effect that COUNT with another JOIN

Tags: sql, join, count

I have three tables

Post

```
ID  Name
1   'Something'
2   'Something else'
3   'One more'
```

Comment

```
ID  PostId  ProfileID  Comment
1   1       1          'Hi my name is' 
2   2       2          'I like cakes'
3   3       3          'I hate cakes'
```

Profile

```
ID  Approved
1   1          
2   0          
3   1
```

I want to count the comments for a post where the profile for the comment is approved

I can select the data from Post and then join a count from Comment fine. But this count should be dependent on if the Profile is approved or not.

The results I am expecting is

CommentCount

```
PostId  Count
1       1
2       0
3       1
```

Comment: Is the `Profile` table 1-1 with the `Comment` one?

Comment: No, a Profile could make many Comments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a nested select like this:

```
SELECT Post.Id, temp.Count
FROM Post
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Post.Id, COUNT(Comment.ID) AS Count
FROM Post
LEFT JOIN Comment ON Comment.PostId = Post.ID
LEFT JOIN Profile ON Profile.ID = Comment.ProfileID
WHERE Profile.Approved = 1
GROUP BY Post.Id)
temp ON temp.Id = Post.ID
```

Which would give you null where there are no posts, rather than no record:

```
1  1
2  null
3  1
```

Just to improve on that, you could use an if to get rid of the nulls

```
SELECT Post.Id, if(temp.Count >= 1,temp.Count,0) as newCount
FROM Post
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Post.Id, COUNT(Comment.ID) AS Count
FROM Post
LEFT JOIN Comment ON Comment.PostId = Post.ID
LEFT JOIN Profile ON Profile.ID = Comment.ProfileID
WHERE Profile.Approved = 1
GROUP BY Post.Id) temp ON temp.Id = Post.ID
```

Which gives you what you originally wanted:

```
1  1
2  0
3  1
```

Note: There is most probably a more elegant solution though!!!!

Answer (score 8):

From the definition of the COUNT function:

> The COUNT function will only count
>   those records in which the field in
>   the brackets is NOT NULL.

This means that simple outer join like this would work:

```
SELECT Post.ID, COUNT(Comment.ID)
  FROM Post LEFT JOIN Comment ON (Post.ID = Comment.PostId)
            LEFT JOIN Profile ON (Profile.ID = Comment.ProfileID AND
                                  Profile.Approved = 1)
 GROUP BY Post.ID
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, it returns only two rows. I need all the rows to be returned even if the `COUNT` is null.

Comment: Sorry, of course it doesn't - see how I moved condition on Profile.Approved to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Post.Id, COUNT(Comment.ID) AS Count
FROM Post
LEFT JOIN Comment ON Comment.PostId = Post.ID
LEFT JOIN Profile ON Profile.ID = Comment.ProfileID
WHERE Profile.Approved = 1
GROUP BY Post.Id
```

Probably you didn't paste it for the sake of the example, but you might evaluate to de-normalize the `Profile` table together with the `Comment` one, by moving the `Approved` column in it.

Comment: Thats a good idea! Although would mean some more coding to make sure that the tables were kept uo to date when a Profile was approved and suspended.

Also, how do you get the table names to appear as code inline in your comment?

Comment: That gives me the correct count, but only for `Posts` that have had `Comments`. I need to return all `Posts` with their counts even if they haven't had any comments. Apologies that I didn't make that clear at the start.